# A functor $\mathcal{F}$ which is not exact but it has an exact power $\mathcal{F}^n$

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories, additive-categories

Is there a functor $\mathcal{F}$ on an abelian category $\mathcal{C}$ which is not exact but there is a natural number $n$ such that $\mathcal{F}^n$ is an exact functor? What about the same question when we replace exactness by half exactness? Namely a  functor which is not left exact but it has a left exact power (or the same for right case)?

**Remark**: We exclude the case that  $\mathcal{F}^n$ is the identity functor for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Why exclude the case that $F^n$ is the identity functor? In any case, that case implies that $F$ is an equivalence so it's automatically exact.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  Yes thanks. BTW is it obvious that commutator group as a functor has no exact power?

Comment: As a functor on what category? $\text{Grp}$ isn't additive.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  But the concept of exactness work, right?

Comment: There are several definitions of exactness that are equivalent for, say, a functor between abelian categories that aren't equivalent for $\text{Grp}$ (as far as I know). Do you want it to preserve short exact sequences or do you want it to preserve finite limits and colimits?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  I mean preserving short exact sequence. but what are some other(non equivalent) definitions?Could you please give a reference?

Comment: For a functor between abelian categories "left exact" is equivalent to "preserves finite limits" and "right exact" is equivalent to "preserves finite colimits" so "exact" (in the sense of preserving short exact sequences) is equivalent to "preserves finite limits and colimits." But that's not true in general. Some people use "left exact" resp. "right exact" to mean "preserves finite limits" resp. "preserves finite colimits" in general but I don't think this is universal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a simple example.  Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the category of $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2)$-modules, and let $\mathcal{F}$ be the functor that takes a module $M$ to the submodule $xM$.  Then $\mathcal{F}$ is not half exact (consider $0\to xM\to M\to M/xM\to 0$ which $\mathcal{F}$ sends to $0\to 0\to xM \to 0\to 0$ which is not exact in the middle unless $xM=0$) but $\mathcal{F}^2=0$ is exact.

Comment: Heh, I was going to answer with a very similar example. :)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff  Thank you for thinking to my question. Would you like to consider the same question about "$G\mapsto G'$?(Please see my conversation with Qiaochu Yuan).